# Embedding react component in existing web project

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-starter-kit

I started a React app using the following [react starter kit](https://github.com/kriasoft/react-starter-kit) and I'm trying to use one of the components that I created in an existing old web project.

After creating the component using the starter kit, I run `npm run build` and got the following chunks:

[image]

Since I'm trying to import my Home component, I copied `home.js` to my old project, and referred to it with React.

What I did in my old project:

```
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js" crossorigin></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js" crossorigin></script>
<script src="components/home.js"></script>
```

Then on the page where I want to show my component:

```
<!-- Load our React component. -->
<script>
const domContainer = document.querySelector('#reactHome');
ReactDOM.render(e(Home), domContainer);
</script>

<div id="reactHome"></div>
```

But console show the folloing errors:

```
home.js:1 Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined
    at home.js:1
(anonymous) @ home.js:1
indexReact.php?page=battleArea:314 Uncaught ReferenceError: Home is not defined
    at indexReact.php?page=battleArea:314
```

Any idea what i'm missing?

Comment: react-starter-kit is isomorphic app type. So you need a Node JS server to serve it. You can not run JS code directly from browser.

Comment: Thanks @TienDuong. Assuming I'm running the nodeJS server - is it still possible to embed the component? If yes, how?

Comment: It is possible. You just need to change your webpack config (if you using webpack to bundle your reactjs) to output commonjs library
https://webpack.js.org/configuration/output/#outputlibrarytarget

Comment: I'm using babel